# Why does GridSearchCV give different optimums on repeated runs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am performing parameter selection using `GridSearchCv` (sklearn package in python) where the model is an Elastic Net with a Logistic loss (i.e a logistic regression with L1- and L2- norm regularization penalties). I am using `SGDClassifier` to implement this model. There are two parameters I am interested in searching the optimal values for: `alpha` (the constant that multiplies the regularization term) and `l1_ratio` (the Elastic Net mixing parameter). My data set has ~300,000 rows. I initialize the model as follows:
`sgd_ela = SGDClassifier(alpha=0.00001, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.1,loss='log', penalty='elasticnet')`
and the searching fxn. as follows:
`GridSearchCV(estimator=sgd_ela, cv=8, param_grid=tune_para)`,
with tuning parameters:
`tune_para = [{'l1_ratio': np.linspace(0.1,1,10).tolist(),'alpha':[0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]}]`.

I get the `best_params` (of `alpha` and `l1_ratio`) upon running the code. However, in *repeated runs*, I do not get the same set of best parameters. I am interested to know why is this the case, and if possible, how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the random seed if you want to get the same result each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. My understanding is that since the optimal values are computed using cross-validation (cv), they have good generelization and hence should hold the same value in repeated runs. You are right in that setting random seed will give the same result, but I am intrigued as to why I don't get the same optimal values across repeated runs, despite the optimal values being computed via cv.?

Comment: Perhaps there are multiple minima with similar scores. Hence a small increase in one score makes the best model one based on a  completely different set of parameters.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I am trying to verify this by comparing the output of the objective function at the optimal value (i.e the `best_score_`) at each repeated run. I'll let you know of my findings just in case you are curious. Thanks a lot again Simon!